# MongoDB DB size is larger after restoration

Tags: database, mongodb, database-backups

I have 3 node MongoDB cluster and I took full backup of it.Then I have restore it into single test node.

In original cluster, there is DB with size 150GB. But after restore backup on my test node same db size is around 263GB.

what could be the reason for it?
(Note: Backup restoration process completed without any errors.)

Comment: How are you performing the size check? What files exist on the cluster vs. on the test node? There are a lot of factors that could be at play, so we'll need to have this narrowed down a bit.

Comment: I have logged into primary and execute "show dbs" command. Based on that I am telling DB sizes are different.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure as to the answer, but it could be that there are storage space reuse inefficiencies at play. More information can be found here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158539/mongodb-restoring-space-after-db-repairdatabase. You may consider taking a look at the `compact` command noted on that answer, documented at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/. That should allow you to free unused disk space resulting from those inefficiencies.